# Passing data between objects/threads in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I create a new thread from a controller like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(makeMovie) toTarget:movieMaker withObject:nil];
```

What is the best way to call methods on the controller from the new thread/movieMaker object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you probably want to use the delegate pattern. In your movie-maker class’s .h file:

```
@protocol MovieMakerDelegate;

@interface MovieMaker : NSObject
{
    id<MovieMakerDelegate> delegate;

    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MovieMakerDelegate> delegate;

...

@end

@protocol MovieMakerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)movieMaker:(MovieMaker *)maker didSomething:(id)result;
@end
```

...and in its .m:

```
@implementation MovieMaker

@synthesize delegate;

...

- (void)makeMovie
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    ...

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(notifyDelegateOfDoingSomethingWithObject:) withObject:someObject waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool release];
}

- (void)notifyDelegateOfDoingSomethingWithObject:(id)someObject
{
    [self.delegate movieMaker:self didSomething:someObject];
}

...

@end
```

Then in your controller’s header, declare that it supports the MovieMakerDelegate protocol, like this:

```
@interface MyController : Whatever <MovieMakerDelegate>
```

and in your .m, before calling your `-detachNewThreadSelector:etc:`, call `movieMaker.delegate = self;`. Implement the `-movieMaker:didSomething:` method on your controller class and you’re good to go.

Comment: thanks for your answer. though this time i think there was a simpler solution as i only need to call one method, but i will definitely use this later. thanks.

Comment: @whg: That doesn't matter. A view generally shouldn't know about its controller anyway. It's still worth making it a delegate relationship, with a protocol, even if the protocol will only have one method. This aids reusability and modifiability (it will be easier to change this app or make a new one/port to a different platform).

Answer (score 2):

You may pass the controller instance to your `makeMovie` method, with the `withObject` parameter.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(makeMovie) toTarget:movieMaker withObject:self];
```

You can also use a singleton-like pattern, if applicable, to retrieve your controller instance from the thread.

Comment: The `makeMovie` method would need to be redefined to accept a parameter (i.e. have the signature `-makeMovie:`). Aside from that, yes, this would also work.

Comment: Just saw your answer. A delegate would be more elegant, that's sure, but maybe a bit confusing for a beginner : )

Comment: I had tried this but I was getting a 'posix_spawn fatal error: 9! ' error, and presumed I was this because I was doing something wrong. But it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) (or similar `performSelector:...` methods), it is the easiest way.